# Google Geo coding service for getting only geocodes

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

We have a pharmacy search application. We are trying to get the the input address from
user and find pharmacies around that address in a user specified raduis.
We are planning to geo code the address entered by user from a third party service. 
After getting the geocodes we will search for pharmacies in our DB around that address and 
display the results. With each result there will be a link which will open a new tab/window of  maps.google.com displaying the location.

If we use the google geocoding API service to get geocodes will they charge for it ? I am not showing the map on my UI. Is that ok or violating the google terms ? Is the 2500 requests/day applicable for this scenario as well ?  I am seeing that MapQuest is a service which will return only geocodes.

Thanks,
Avinash.

Comment: You need a legal opinion to know if you are violating Google's terms of service.  This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Double check with Google's Terms of Service, but generally they begin denying your API requests after you reach your limit.  If you are a repeat offender, they may permanently prevent your IP from using their API.  The limit is on the calls that you make to the Geocoding API and is unrelated to whether you display a map using their maps api.  The following includes strategies for how to work within these limits: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

Answer (score 0):

[MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com) just released their [Open Geocoding Web Service](http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/), which is built using data provided by the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) community, and (currently) does not have a limit on the number of geocoding requests that can be made.